# ajax request base64 image performance issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, image

I am trying to retrieve list of images in base64 format using jquery ajax request from web api. The database query is fast, but the problem is the ajax response from the server to client is slow. It takes about 7 seconds for 4 images with each image around 1 - 2mb. Therefore, I need to do some performance tuning regarding this issue.

Few restrictions: 
- No storing the existing image as file in disk (currently store in database)
- Not allow to tamper database structure (eg: resize image during upload and save the smaller size image into another column)
- The image store must still be in high quality since the image can be enlarge when click.

Few things that came into my mind: 
- prevent additional request when refreshing the page by storing in local storage (but local storage size limit is not enough to store the images?)
- crop the image in server side before send to client (but not sure how fast can this increase the performance)

Hope that someone can give me some guidance on this issue.

Comment: _"trying to retrieve list of images in base64 format using jquery ajax request from web api"_ Is requirement to convert images uploaded by user to `base64` ? or, retrieve `base64` strings from server ?

Comment: @guest271314 retrieve base64 image strings from server

Comment: `base64` strings could have `length` that requires a span of time to process . Tried returning `Blob`of image file from server , convert to `base64` string at response ? , or `Blob` of `base64` string ?

Comment: @guest271314 hi i am not pretty sure what are you trying to explain about. Currently I have an encoded base64 string in database. The ajax request is retrieving the base 64 string, not blob. Do you mean i should convert the base64 string to blob before returning?

Comment: Try using `XMLHttpRequest` , setting `responseType` to `"blob"`

Comment: @guest271314 I am just about to ask is it possible to return blob file using jquery ajax. So i suppose that it is not impossible? Cause the whole project is being written in jquery ajax so i would try to avoid using xmlhttprequest if possible.

Comment: See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1525 , http://artandlogic.com/2013/11/jquery-ajax-blobs-and-array-buffers/

Comment: @guest271314 current the image is stored as base64 string in database. So how could i request it as blob ?

Comment: Tried patterns described at posts above ?